# Use value of stored procedure in another stored procedure in PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is there any way of calling a stored procedure from another stored procedure, and use retrieved value (from the second procedure) back in the first one?

Comment: Whats the output type of the inner stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-- procedure #1
create or replace procedure Proc1(p_RetValue out SomeDataType) 
is
begin
  -- any logic goes here
  p_retValue := 5+5; -- for example. Let's assume that the SomeDataType is number;   
end;

-- second procedure 
create or replace procedure Proc2 is
  l_variable number;
begin
  Proc1(l_variable);  -- the value 10 will be assigned to l_variable;
end;
```

Comment: The second procedure needs some modifications:

`create or replace procedure Proc2 (l_variable out number)
is
begin
  Proc1(l_variable);  -- the value 10 will be assigned to l_variable;
end;`